# SQL - can I use OR and LIKE on the same line of a query?

Tags: sql, jsp

I have a search function were I can find Address Line 1 in my database, but I was wondering if it is possible to find addressline 1,2,3,4,5 which are all separate attributes on the same line, depending what the user searches for. See code below. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

**This Works:**

```
<sql:query var ="NameCheck" scope = "session" dataSource = "${bookdB}">

    SELECT * FROM Company   
    WHERE Address_1 LIKE ?

    <sql:param value = "%${param.category}%" />

</sql:query>
```

---

**Is this possible in some form of syntax (either '||', 'OR' operator).**

```
SELECT * FROM Company
WHERE Address_1 OR Address_2 OR Address_3 OR Address_4 OR Address_5 LIKE ?
```

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain you're not executing SQL from HTML.

Comment: Still don't see the reason for the minuses.

Comment: well its JSP, the minuses i guess you mean underscores are just the attribute names. probably should take them out. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you use is not correct.

You'll have to do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM Company
WHERE Address_1 LIKE ...
   OR Address_2 LIKE ...
   OR Address_3 LIKE ...
   OR Address_4 LIKE ...
   OR Address_5 LIKE ...
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us. I'm getting a compile error in my stack trace when I use the code above "COUNT field incorrect". any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

In Sql, yes you can use `OR` instead of `||`, however this is the only way to select the rows in conditions, but you must complete each and every condition and then start a new condition like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Company
WHERE Address_1 LIKE 
OR Address_2 LIKE %a OR 
Address_3 LIKE %a OR 
Address_4 LIKE%a OR 
Address_5 LIKE %a
```

Computer won't change its algorithm, so you should stick to its language :)

To search multiple addresses you can use `AND` and then write them in the HTML. You can use `OR` when one condition is not true, then move to the next one. This way, you must close the condition before `OR` operator.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us. I'm getting a compile error in my stack trace when I use the code above "COUNT field incorrect". any ideas???

Comment: This might be an issue, because the `Count ()` method is being provided with some invalid arguments. In simple words, your data to count is not valid, it might be `null`.

Comment: all fields in the database have values though.

Comment: Can you share some more info about the code that gets the value?

Comment: sure thing. I added further code to the question above. I have a search form in a JSP file, this file has one address input box, when the search button is pressed. The value of the input box is sent to a different JSP file where the SQL statement is above. This then forwards to another JSP file automatically where the address search results are outputted. I have this is working for address line 1, but i want to get address line 1-5 to do this, using the same input box on the search form.

Comment: This might be in a different datatype, you might try Googling it! I am not aware with JSP.